# JavaScript how to stop the valid true pop up after click the ok alert

Tags: javascript, popup

How can I stop this from popping up after clicking the OK alert? (Your answer is correct). After clicking OK, the below image pops up.

[image: A popup dialog]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nameValidate() {
    var answer = {Korea: 'seul'}, 
        valid = false, 
        input_value = document.getElementById('name').value.toLowerCase();

    if (input_value == answer.Korea) {
       alert ("Your answer is correct!");
       valid = true;
    }
    alert(valid);
    return valid;
}   
</script>
```

Comment: If you do not want the alert than remove the `alert(valid);`! But how will they know if it is invalid? Hint: use an `else`

Comment: This is a Javascript *alert*, so just remove `alert(valid);` and you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the popup to show true after "Your answer is correct!" but you still want to show the popup false when the answer is wrong, then replace your function with this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function nameValidate() {
            var answer = {Korea: 'seul'}, 
                valid = false, 
                input_value = document.getElementById('name').value.toLowerCase();

            if (input_value == answer.Korea) {
               alert ("Your answer is correct!");
               valid = true;
            }
            else if(input_value === "")
            {
               alert("You need to enter an answer")
            }
            else{
               alert("Your answer is incorrect!");
            }
            return valid;
        }   
        </script>
```

Comment: your code works but what if the answer is wrong or the text box is empty, i want to say. The answer is wrong instead of the false.

Comment: Check the updated code above. please set my answer as correct. this code will say "Your answer is correct" if the answer is correct. "You need to enter an answer" if the answer is empty. And "Your answer is incorrect" if the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling it to pop up an alert here: `alert(valid);` 
Just remove that statement.

```
function nameValidate() { 
     var answer = {Korea: 'seul'}, 
     valid = false, 
     input_value = document.getElementById('name').value.toLowerCase(); 
     if (input_value == answer.Korea) {
                alert ("Your answer is correct!"); 
                valid = true; 
      }  
      return valid; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand your question. But you dont want the alert popup to show true? you just want the alert to show, "your answer is correct"?

Then just Remove :

```
alert(valid);
```

Comment: Hi, i only want to see the alert "Your answers is correct" but after clicking ok, another popup appears that is the image above.

Comment: Yes ok, Then this answer and Birgit Martinelle's answer is correct. 

Valid = true;
alert(Valid);

You see the problem?
So just remove the alert(valid);

Comment: i need the alerts to validate the page but i don't want the second popup to appear.

Comment: Well, you dont need an alert to validate the page. Your return valid are sending back the bool value.

The alert is the popup. So if you write alert(valid) it will show the value of valid like. If the answer not is Korea then the popup will show false.

If the answer is Korea, the popup will first show "Your answer is correct!" then it will show True because you set alert(true) after the if. 

Just remove the alert(true) and your code will do exactly the same as it does now except it wont show the true popup.